# Jquery Ajax url to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to call a controller from a function through Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "@Url.Action("items_status", "Part_views_index")",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError) {
                alert(xmlHttpRequest + "|" + errorText + "|" + thrownError);
        },
  success: function (data) {
            UpdateItemsData(data);
        }
 });
```

But this return a 404, here is the controller part:

```
public class Partviewsindex : Controller
{
    // Controller for partial view 
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult items_status()
    {
        var chart = new getItemsStatusChart();
        var chartData = chart.GetPieChart();
        return Json(chartData);
    }
}
```

}

Any idea?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I found the problem, I needed to add Controller at the end of the controller name and the url is now formed like this in my javascript file:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Partviewsindex/items_status',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError) {
            alert(xmlHttpRequest + "|" + errorText + "|" + thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            UpdateItemsData(data);
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: why are you trying to load a partial view ? im not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm not sure I need a partial view either, but the problem doesn't seem to be the partial view, I'm having a 404 when calling the ajax code. Thanks

Comment: Your controller classes really do need the word "Controller" at the end.  This is part of how MVC wires things up.  Try "PartviewsindexController".

Comment: Just tried to add it but still the same 404 error:

GET http://localhost:58893/PartviewsindexController/items_status 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like it is written here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269(v=vs.100).aspx you need the word "controller" as a sufix its a standard in model-view-controller so your controller name should be PartviewsindexController

Comment: I added the Controller at the end without more success:

GET http://localhost:58893/PartviewsindexController/items_status 404 (Not Found)

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to recreate it as a normal view with the sufix

Answer (score 0):

please press F12 and look the network tab, and look witch URL are you really making you post.

I think you are rounding your `url:` with "" and you are making a request to this URL: `http://.. "@Url.Action("items_status", "Part_views_index")"`

Try simply change this it should work:

```
 url: '../Partviewsindex/items_status'
```

Comment: In both case the url formed is:

http://localhost:58893/Partviewsindex/items_status Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I can't figure what it's expecting.